# Why "lifting state up" in react doesn't always work?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I was reading the redux documentation and it said:

> ...the simplicity can break down when we have multiple components that need to share and use the same state, especially if those components are located in different parts of the application. Sometimes this can be solved by "lifting state up" to parent components, but that doesn't always help.

Before going through the documentation of redux, I was constantly thinking that sharing state throughout the application can actually be done by lifting state up but redux documentation just says that it doesn't always help without any examples or explanations.

Can anyone give an example on when wouldn't lifting state up help? I'm new to react and haven't yet faced an issue where I have to share the state globally by using a library such as redux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not so much that it *can't* be done.  It's more that it will make things terribly ugly and force prop drilling.  If I have a global user, I don't won't to be forced to pass that user state down 6 levels through other components that do nothing with the user object besides forwarding it down further to something that **does** use it.

That's the point of `React.Context` and Redux.

Below are 2 examples using drilling and context.  `<Parent/>` renders state, `<Middle/>` does nothing, `<Child/>` renders state and lets you set it through buttons.  Here is a table showing their dependencies

| Component | Needs State | Needs Setter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Parent | Yes | No |
| Middle | No | No |
| Child | Yes | Yes |

### Drilling

Consider the example below that uses drilling.  `<Parent/>` hosts the state including the actual value as well as the way to change it even though it only cares about displaying it. `<Middle/>` doesn't care about the state at all, but has to know about it anyway in order to forward it to `<Child/>`.  `<Child>` needs to know everything about the state because it wants to render it as well as mutate it.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Parent = () => {
  const [some, setSome] = useState("foobar");

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Parent</h2>
      <div>I care about some because I want to display it: "{some}"</div>
      <Middle some={some} onThing={v => setSome(v)} />
    </div>
  )
};

const Child = ({some, onThing}) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Child</h2>
    <div>I care about some a lot and will render it: "{some}" and do stuff to change it</div>
    <button onClick={() => onThing("hello")}>Change to "hello"</button>
    <button onClick={() => onThing("world")}>Change to "world"</button>
  </div>
);

const Middle = ({some, onThing}) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Middle</h2>
    <div>I don't care about some at all and try not to do anything with it</div>
    <Child some={some} onThing={onThing} />
  </div>
);

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>This is the App Using Drilling</h1>
    <Parent />
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

### Context

Now consider this example using contexts.  `<Parent/>` only cares about the actual value and only pulls that out of the context.  `<Middle/>` is dead simple and has no props.  It **just** renders `<Child/>`.  `<Child/>` looks very similar except it gets the state and setter from `useContext` instead of its props.

```js
const {useState, useContext, createContext} = React;

const SomeContext = createContext(null);

const SomeProvider = ({children}) => {
  const someState = useState("foobar");

  return (
    <SomeContext.Provider
      value={someState}
      children={children}
    />
  )
}

const Parent = () => {
  const [some] = useContext(SomeContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Parent</h2>
      <div>I care about some because I want to display it: "{some}"</div>
      <Middle />
    </div>
  );
};

const Child = () => {
  const [some, setSome] = useContext(SomeContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Child</h2>
      <div>I care about some a lot and will render it: "{some}" and do stuff to change it</div>
      <button onClick={() => setSome("hello")}>Change to "hello"</button>
      <button onClick={() => setSome("world")}>Change to "world"</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Middle = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Middle</h2>
    <div>I don't care about some at all and try not to do anything with it</div>
    <Child />
  </div>
);

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>This is the App Using Context</h1>
    <SomeProvider>
      <Parent />
    </SomeProvider>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that if you have a lot of components in your tree that needs to share the same piece of state and they are located far away, you have to "lift up" that state to the main ancestor and then you have to pass the `state prop` down the `hierarchy` on each children component.

This can pollute the props of every component in the `hierarchy`.

However with the `Context API` you can ease this problem.

Comment: And how many components is considered "a lot". Are 2 components considered too many? What is the recommended threshold?